# Docker eating up disk space /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-machine, docker-registry

We are using Docker and have a production issue. We are running out of space in our root volume since docker device mapper is eating up space.

Is there a way to reduce the disk space to a proper size *without* having to remove Docker and reinstall from scratch?

The docker version we are using is

```html
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        Thu Sep 10 19:08:45 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        Thu Sep 10 19:08:45 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

We have 20 GB root volume and 12GB is used by docker. We are left with only few GB of space. The below docker file is 12GB

```html
/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
```

We have also tried removing unused old docker images by using the command

```html
docker images -q |xargs docker rmi
```

but still it doesn't work.

Appreciate if someone could let me know if there is any way to reduce the disk space to a proper size WITHOUT having to remove docker and reinstall from scratch? Also we don't want to copy files to a new location and do a softlink.

The current docker command outputs are

```html
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
92558da1291a        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:27.6         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   19 hours ago        Up 19 hours                             quality
2a0497fdbaa7        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:21.9         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours                             rmCallMetrics
1f5f93604e8f        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/loanservicing:8.3   "/root/go/src/loanser"   2 days ago          Up 2 days                               ls_vznagtingestor
88b4d764c03c        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:21.3         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               dlrMgmt
bd0ecfe2f9ae        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:12.1         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               userRMAttributesIngestor
8bd3d626f7d7        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:12.1         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               dhPointsPerHour
383e257d2f31        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:12.1         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               dhPrimeSameDayContracts
6727c76221e4        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:12.1         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               rbcARMAgentsIngestor
527327182f0a        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:19.6         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               dhDealerOrg
1ece1b0f61a7        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:25.6         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               shawMasterFileLvl1
8aefc887e1f5        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:12.1         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               dhExhaustEveryEffort
94b89a019b8c        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:22.1         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               asmSummaryWeeklyMetrics
e64e9fe9c7e2        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:12.1         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               dhForecastedMetrics
f39c5fef33d3        dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus:12.1         "/root/go/src/plexus/"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                               dhMTDContracts
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]#
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]#
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]# docker ps -qa
92558da1291a
2a0497fdbaa7
1f5f93604e8f
88b4d764c03c
bd0ecfe2f9ae
8bd3d626f7d7
383e257d2f31
6727c76221e4
527327182f0a
1ece1b0f61a7
8aefc887e1f5
94b89a019b8c
e64e9fe9c7e2
f39c5fef33d3
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]#
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]#
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY                                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus          27.6                75fd00165ca4        19 hours ago        976.7 MB
dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/loanservicing   8.3                 84bf8f83af5b        2 days ago          973.4 MB
dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus          25.6                672f56435428        13 days ago         976.9 MB
dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus          22.1                3f0d00cf334a        3 weeks ago         976.4 MB
dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus          21.9                783a4e812972        3 weeks ago         976.4 MB
dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus          21.3                28a70e5a5621        3 weeks ago         976.3 MB
dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus          19.6                b85f1fd3e822        4 weeks ago         975.4 MB
dockyardaws.kdc.capitalone.com/statim/plexus          12.1                ce572ad85088        9 weeks ago         971.8 MB
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]#
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]#
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]# docker images -q
75fd00165ca4
84bf8f83af5b
672f56435428
3f0d00cf334a
783a4e812972
28a70e5a5621
b85f1fd3e822
ce572ad85088
[root@ip-10-202-69-58 ~]#
```

Comment: How big are these images? Do a `docker history` on one or two of them. If you aren't reusing layers properly, it will eat up space quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing docker containers which are not running:

```
docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
```

And then remove the unused docker images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Comment: I have update my post with docker command outputs. Could you please let me know if I can still go ahead and do "docker rm $(docker ps -qa)" and "docker rmi $(docker images -q)".

Comment: Since this is production I wanted to confirm if this doesn't impact our currently running docker containers. Appreciate your help

Comment: @Nissar I've updated my response: now it checks for exited containers. I've ran this command in production myself and I didn't have any problem. I wish that docker make it easier to clean up unused images at some point...